# Azure PowerShell - Selecting Subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I need to select my Azure Subscription in Azure PowerShell.

I copy/paste the Subscription ID (to ensure no typos) from the `Azure Management Portal`, it's a hex-string:

[image]

When I run:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId '0300...'
```

I get an error message:

```
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription id 0300... doesn't exist.
```

I know my subscription ID is correctly copied from the settings in `Azure Management Portal`, I even did a BeyondCompare to make sure.

I'm wondering about security... am I missing something?  Do I need to somehow provide my Azure credentials?  It wouldn't make sense to just allow anyone to select any Azure subscription, unless the Subscription ID is supposed to be super-secret, like an SSN.

Comment: `Select-AzureRmSubscription` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to log on to your Azure account first:

> To start working with the Azure Service Management cmdlets, first log
>   on to your Azure account. To log on to your account, run the following
>   command:
>
> `Add-AzureAccount`
>
> After logging into Azure, Azure PowerShell creates a context for the
>   given session. That context contains the Azure PowerShell environment,
>   account, tenant, and subscription that will be used for all cmdlets
>   within that session. Now you are ready to use the modules below.
>
> - Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azure-ps?view=azuresmps-3.7.0

Comment: Thank you ... that turned out to be it.  The article I had been working off:
 [Convert existing dynamic VIP to Reserved IP](http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/convert-existing-dynamic-vip-reserved-ip-addresses-azure/) left out this step.

Comment: No problem, glad it was simple :).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Log on to your Azure Account using `Add-AzAccount` or `Add-AzureAccount`

then you can check all subscriptions available in your account

using command `Get-AzSubscription`

it will return you `Name, Id , TenantId , State`  of Subscription

Then you can select any Subscription by running either of following commands

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
Select-AzSubscription -Tenant 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```